# React calling callback interferes with useState

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page that has an array of child components (Card). In the parent, I save in state how many cards have been clicked. So each card has a callback function that when clicked updates the variable. That works ok, except that I also save in local state for each card whether they have been clicked or not (they flip over when clicked). But when I call the callback, updating the local state doesn't work (or the component gets reset, or I don't know what happens), but it doesn't update the local state.

Parent:

```js
export default function Game() {
  const [flipState, setFlipState] = useState(0);
  function flipCallback() {
    if (flipState == 0) {
      setFlipState(1);
    } else if (flipState == 1) {
      setFlipState(2);
    } else if (flipState == 2) {
      setFlipState(0);
    }
  }
  let tileOrder = [...Array(36).keys()];

  let cards = tileOrder.map((e, i) => (
    <Card
      key={"card" + i + "-" + e}
      iconSet={1}
      index={i}
      speed={1}
      callback={() => {
        flipCallback();
      }}
      state={flipState}
    />
  ));

  return (<div>{cards}</div>);
}
```

The child:

```js
export default function Card({ iconSet, index, speed, callback, state }) {
  const [isFlipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);

const handleFlip = () => {
    if (isFlipped === false && (state === 0 || state === 1)) {
      callback();
      setFlipped(true);
      console.log(isFlipped); // This is false, unless I comment out the callback above
      if (state == 2) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setFlipped(false);
        }, speed * 1000);
      }
    }
  };

  const statusUpdate = useCallback(() => {
    if (isFlipped && state == 2) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFlipped(false);
        callback();
      }, speed * 1000);
    }
  }, [isFlipped, speed, state, callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    if (isMounted) {
      setCardState(state);
      statusUpdate();
    }
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [state, statusUpdate]);

  return (
    <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
      <button onClick={handleFlip}>
        Blank
      </button>
      <button>{index}</button>
    </ReactCardFlip>
  );
}
```

Comment: when you call `callback()` in `handleFlip` fn in child then the component is re-rendered and you again initialize `isFlipped` to false. So, what you could do is treat your child component as a controlled component & set state of child component (i.e. whether it is flipped or not) from the parent component. So, essentially, pass down whether child is flipped from parent component.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought was happening.

Comment: glad I could help, should I then add my comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure. I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `callback()` in `handleFlip` fn in child then the component is re-rendered and you again initialize `isFlipped` to false. So, what you could do is treat your child component as a controlled component & set state of child component (i.e. whether it is flipped or not) from the parent component. So, essentially, pass down whether child is flipped from parent component.